# Access data from vectors

Tags: r, vector

I need help to load data from vectors

On one hand, I´ve got a data frame with th individual identification of products (around 13.000 obs). On the other hand I've got several vectors (50) with all the individual IDs of products that belongs to the same production batch.

I've created a dataframe with the names of all the vectors.

Now, I must access the data of each vector separately, to compare with the individual ID stored in the data frame.

The final result is add a new column in the data frame with the batch name.

```
        ID_df=data.frame(ID=c(1:10),LOT=("W/O Lot"),stringsAsFactors = F)

        Lot_a=c(1:3)
        Lot_b=c(4:6)
        Lot_c=c(7:9)

        index=as.data.frame(ls(pattern = 'Lot_'))

        ID_df[which(ID_df$ID %in% Lot_a),2]='Lot_a'
        ID_df[which(ID_df$ID %in% Lot_b),2]='Lot_b'
        ID_df[which(ID_df$ID %in% Lot_c),2]='Lot_c'

        ID_df


           ID     LOT
        1   1   Lot_a
        2   2   Lot_a
        3   3   Lot_a
        4   4   Lot_b
        5   5   Lot_b
        6   6   Lot_b
        7   7   Lot_c
        8   8   Lot_c
        9   9   Lot_c
        10 10 W/O Lot
```

I tried with a FOR loop, but only can read the name of the vector in the index dataframe instead of the data contained in it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
eval(parse(text = index[1]))
```

If I understood your question correctly, you want R to evaluate a string as if it is R code.  You would use `eval` to do so.

The above would give you 1,2,3 as output.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, it's much better to store your data in a list if they are related, but if they are already in the global environment, you can use `ls` and `mget` to get a list of data matched by your `ls` vector:

```
mget(ls(pattern = "vector_"))
```

**Result:**

```
$vector_a
[1] 1 2 3

$vector_b
[1] 4 5 6

$vector_c
[1] 7 8 9
```